# How to create referenceable label node above section in sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

I am creating a custom directive in sphinx.
This directive lists all possible objects (each one in separate section).

Now I would like those objects to be referenceable from other parts (files) of documentation.

I was trying to do something very simple like:

```
class MyDirective(Directive):
    def run(self, obj):
        id1 = 'object-unique-id1'
        id2 = 'object-unique-id2'
        label = nodes.label('abc1', refid=id1)
        section = nodes.section(ids=[id2])
        section += nodes.title(text='abc')
        section += label
        return [section]
```

but it doesn't allow me to reference to this section neither by :ref:`object-unique-id1`, :ref:`object-unique-id2` nor :ref:`abc`.

So my question is: How to create node that can be referenced ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a target immediately before the section appears to work. Something like:

```
class MyDirective(Directive):
    def run(self, obj):
        titleTxt = 'abc'
        lineno = self.state_machine.abs_line_number()
        target = nodes.target()
        section = nodes.section()

        # titleTxt appears to need to be same as the section's title text
        self.state.add_target(titleTxt, '', target, lineno) 
        section += nodes.title(titleTxt, '')

        return [target, section]
```

Note the call to `self.state.add_target`.

Somewhere later in the build the target is magically created and should be able to refer to your section with

```
:ref:`abc`
```

anywhere in your project.